# Unsupported URL" Error When Making HTTP Request in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, rest

I've written an application in SwiftUI where I'm trying to make an HTTP request to an external server to fetch JSON data. I'm using URLSession to perform this request. However, when I attempt to make the request, I'm getting an "unsupported URL" error.

I've double-checked the URL address and it seems to be formatted correctly. Is there something I'm overlooking or something I need to do to fix this error?

My code looks something like this:

```
struct GroupsResponse: Decodable {
        let results: [Groups]
    }

    struct Groups: Decodable {
        let Id: Int
        let Descriere: String
    }
    
    private func fetchGroupsFromAPI() async throws -> [Groups] {
        let url = URL(string: "http://orar.usarb.md/api/access/getGroups")!
        var request = URLRequest(url: url)
        request.httpMethod = "POST"
        
        let (data, _) = try await URLSession.shared.data(for: request)
        
        let decoded = try JSONDecoder().decode(GroupsResponse.self, from: data)
        print(decoded)
        return decoded.results
    }

 private func button(_ title: String, color: Color) -> some View {
        Button(action: {
            Task {
                do {
                    let movies = try await fetchGroupsFromAPI()

                    print(movies)
                } catch {
                    print(error)
                }
            }
        }) {
            Text(title)
                .frame(height: 40)
                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
                .background(color.opacity(0.5))
                .foregroundColor(.black)
        }
    }
}
```

I try to make request but i have this error

Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1002 "unsupported URL" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=unsupported URL, NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=/api/access/getGroups, NSErrorFailingURLKey=/api/access/getGroups, _NSURLErrorRelatedURLSessionTaskErrorKey=(
"LocalDataTask <39D779DF-E734-4D65-8722-23F3843FB2D9>.<3>"
), _NSURLErrorFailingURLSessionTaskErrorKey=LocalDataTask <39D779DF-E734-4D65-8722-23F3843FB2D9>.<3>, NSUnderlyingError=0x600000c68390 {Error Domain=kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork Code=-1002 "(null)"}}

[I modify info file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mnCRO.png)

In documentation i have POST request but not GET

I try to modify info, i try to rebuild project and make some changes in code structure

```
struct GroupsResponse: Decodable {
        let results: [Groups]
    }

    struct Groups: Decodable {
        let Id: Int
        let Descriere: String
    }
    
    func fetchGroupsFromAPI() async throws -> [Groups] {
        let url = URL(string: "http://orar.usarb.md/api/access/getGroups")!

        let (data, _) = try await URLSession.shared.data(from: url)

        let decoded = try JSONDecoder().decode(GroupsResponse.self, from: data)

        return decoded.results
    }
```

Comment: Hint: App Transport Security Settings

Comment: There's important info about this issue here: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/bundleresources/information_property_list/nsapptransportsecurity/nsallowsarbitraryloads

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, Apple doesn't allow making HTTP requests for security reasons unless you enable `Allow Arbitrary Loads` in the Info.plist file. So, you can enable that key in plist file for testing by:

> Project -> Select Target -> Info -> Add the key